# The app crashes when i put the parse code inside it

Tags: android, parse-platform

My app has two Activities, it works fine but once i put these lines of code

```
Parse.initialize(this, "app id", "client id");

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

The app crashes. I tried to delete it from the first activity and put it in the second activity, when i did this, the app works fine until the app moves to the second activity, it crashes then

```
04-21 17:37:59.199  22529-22529/com.example.cashmoney.barakah     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bolts.Task
        at com.parse.ParseInstallation.hasCurrentInstallationAsync(ParseInstallation.java:88)
        at com.parse.GcmRegistrar.updateAsync(GcmRegistrar.java:96)
        at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:240)
        at com.example.cashmoney.barakah.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5193)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2189)
        at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5166)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: **post the stack trace from logcat**

Comment: check your ParceACL is  defined or not.

Comment: It looks like you need to add a reference to the bolts library. If you're using gradle the following should work: `dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
}`

Comment: Good to hear :). I'll add it as an answer then you can accept it so others with the same problem can see

Comment: i tried to accept but i have to have at least 15 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a reference to the bolts library. If you're using gradle the following should work:

```
dependencies { compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0' }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Parse initialization should be placed in the onCreate Method of the Application class.

```
Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION ID",
            "CLIENT KEY");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

See the Parse documentation:

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing

**Hint**
You should also not post your application key and ID.